# UINavigationController in combination with UITableView = wasted memory?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm wondering: if I have a folder strucure in my model and want to view it on the PC, I'd go for a tree control. Expanding a node would lazy-load the child controls.
On the iPhone however I'm stuck to one level at a time and I want to use a navigation controller to allow the user to go one level up.
But what is good design here? Push a new UITableViewController whenever a subfolder is entered? If the hierarchy is deep enough, one will end up with a lot of stacked controllers.
Or is it better to "fake" the navigation controller and alway repopulate the table with the current child nodes and update the "back" button with teh parent node's name?

René

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out myself. It really is thought to push controllers all the time. The controller however can be the same. The views get unloaded automatically by the OS.
So no need to fake navigation.